# Spark 2.3.0: Unable to find MapGroupsWithStateFunction function

Tags: maven, apache-spark

Here is the snapshot of the dependency I have mentioned in my pom.xml, However, I am unable to find MapGroupsWithStateFunction.

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapGroupsWithStateFunction; // It says This cannot be resolved.

Do I miss anything out here?

```
<properties>
    <spark.core.version>2.3.0</spark.core.version>
    <kafka.version>1.1.0</kafka.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
 <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try adding `spark-sql_2.11` to your POM.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I added below dependency however no success.
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @GunjanShah For using `mapGroupsWithState`, we have to use `Dataset`, not `DataFrame`. If you are trying to use it on `DataFrame`.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian - That's fine but at first place why it is not resolved even if i have included 2.3.0 version dependencies in my pom as mentioned above?

Comment: I have been able to workaround it by using mapWithState, which works on JavaPairDStream.